# Why do my tokio tasks quit before finishing?

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

The program below is supposed to print at regular intervals from multiple threads, but it is not working as I expected:

```toml
# Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "0.3", features = ["full"] }
```

```rust
use tokio::prelude::*; //0.3.4
use tokio::runtime::Builder;
use tokio::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let rt = Builder::new_multi_thread()
        .enable_all()
        .thread_stack_size(3 * 1024 * 1024)
        .build()
        .unwrap();

    rt.block_on(async {
        tokio::spawn(print_thread(1));
        tokio::spawn(print_thread(2));
        tokio::spawn(print_thread(3));
        tokio::spawn(print_thread(4));
    });
}

async fn print_thread(thread_num: usize) {
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        println!("thread{}-start", thread_num);
        loop {
            tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000)).await;
            println!("thread{}-running", thread_num);
        }
        println!("thread{}-start", thread_num);
    });
}
```

When running this, I get:

```
$ cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.64s
     Running `target/debug/time_test`
thread1-start
thread2-start
thread3-start
thread4-start
$
```

I expected to see messages "threadN-running", but there is no further output. I don't know why the program suddenly quits. Can someone please tell me the cause?

Comment: By the way, you `tokio::spawn` twice, once in main, and once more in the thread function itself

Comment: task are not thread. I advice you to read the tokio documentation entirely tokio is not a thing you can make work without read a lot about it

Comment: Your `print_thread` function spawns a new task, then returns immediately without waiting for this task to run. Your main function exits as soon as all the `print_thread` functions have returned.

Comment: Thank you.
Actually, the code originally did some other processing, and I erased the parts not related to the question.
This has resulted in code that calls tokio::spawn twice for no reason.

As you all have pointed out, I don't seem to have a good understanding of tokio.
I will read the documentation carefully.

Comment: Related: [How can I stop an async program from terminating when any task is running?](/q/66995937/2189130)

Answer (score 3):

The outer `async` block:

```
rt.block_on(async { ... })
```

does not join the spawned future, so it ends immediately after spawning it. This ends the `block_on` and also `main`, before the inner `task` has time to `sleep` and `println!`. The tasks are killed before they can finish executing.

You can solve this by wrapping the `block_on` in a never ending loop:

```rust
loop {
  rt.block_on(async {
    tokio::spawn(print_thread(1));
    tokio::spawn(print_thread(2));
    tokio::spawn(print_thread(3));
    tokio::spawn(print_thread(4));
  });
}
```

Now the tokio executor has all the time it needs to spawn the `tasks`, `sleep`, and print the messages to the console. However, this `loop` will be costly cpu wise. Another option is to use [`std::future::pending`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/future/fn.pending.html) which was stabilized as of Rust 1.48. This will create a future which never resolves, representing a computation that never finishes:

```rust
rt.block_on(async {
 ...
});

std::future::pending().await;
unreachable!();
```

Also, as @AlexLarionov mentioned, you are actually spawning a `task` twice:

```
// 1st task
tokio::spawn(print_thread(1))

// 2nd task
async fn print_thread(thread_num: usize) {
    tokio::spawn(async move { ... });
}
```

This second spawn is unnecessary, and your `print_thread` function can be simplified to the following:

```rust
async fn print_thread(thread_num: usize) {
    println!("thread{}-start", thread_num);
    loop {
        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000)).await;
        println!("thread{}-running", thread_num);
    }
    // Note that this is unreachable
    println!("thread{}-start", thread_num);
}
```

Note that for use case `tokio::time::sleep` is probably not the best option. To run something regularly on a schedule, you can use [`tokoi::time::interval`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.3.4/tokio/time/fn.interval.html):

```rust
async fn print_thread(thread_num: usize) {
    println!("thread{}-start", thread_num);
    let mut interval = tokio::time::interval(Duration::from_millis(100));
    loop {
      interval.tick().await;
      println!("thread{}-running", thread_num);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the cause as well as best practices.
The methods you have taught me have worked well.
As others have pointed out, I realized that my misunderstanding about tokio.
I will read the tokio documentation carefully.